Showing the $\mathcal{P}$ subalgebra generated by a subset $S$ is the intersection of all $\mathcal P$ subalgebras containing $S$.
This question is intended to be as general as possible when defining "subalgebra".  Hence the universal-algebra tag and the category-theory tag.
The Question:

Show that for an algebra $A$, the $\mathcal P$ subalgebra generated by $S\subseteq A$ is
$$\langle\langle S\rangle\rangle^\mathcal{P}_A=\bigcap_{B\le_{\mathcal P}A\\ S\subseteq B}B,$$
where $B\le_{\mathcal P}A$ means "$B$ is a subalgebra of $A$ with property $\mathcal{P}$".

Here $\langle\langle S\rangle\rangle^\mathcal{P}_A$ is the subalgebra of $A$ with property $\mathcal P$ generated by $S$.
The Details:
I'm not sure how to define $\langle\langle S\rangle\rangle^\mathcal{P}_A$ properly without word lengths, and hence associativity, but if I recall correctly, there is a way around that for nonassociative algebras; either way, please assume the maximum level of generality, as is fitting with the spirit of the question.
What is $\mathcal P$?
This is, to put is loosely, in the style of universal algebra, meant to capture the analogue of, say, normality of a subgroup of a group, so that if $\mathcal P$ is normality, then $\le_{\mathcal P}=\unlhd$.
Thoughts:
I think, as I said in the preamble, this requires universal algebra and/or category theory.  Perhaps these two perspectives give different answers.  Who knows?  I don't.
Why do I think this?
Because I have a vague recollection of Burris et al.'s book on universal algebra and can see some sort of universal property in the categorical sense being used here.

Because I struggle to make this precise whilst also keeping it as general as possible, I have included the soft-question tag.

Edit: A definition of $\langle\langle S\rangle\rangle^\mathcal{P}_A$ that might work is "the smallest $\mathcal P$ subalgebra of $A$ containing $S$".

It follows from elementary set theory that if $F$ is a nonempty family of sets, then "the smallest element of $F$" exists iff $\bigcap F\in F$ (and the smallest element must be this intersection). So it seems to me that with the definition of "generated P subalgebra" in your edit, the equality you want is true but perhaps more trivial than you were hoping. In the usual settings where we have this equality (eg normal subgroups), I think the interesting fact is that such a smallest P subalgebra exists at all - or equivalently, that this intersection is a P subalgebra.

That's an answer, @IzaakvanDongen.  Please write it out as such and I will accept it :)

A useful sufficient condition on $\mathcal{P}$ for the construction to work is that $\mathcal{P}$ is closed under arbitrary intersections.  And a useful special case of that is that the condition holds if $\mathcal{P}$ is a conjunction of some "closure conditions" of the form $x_1 \in B \wedge \cdots \wedge x_n \in B \rightarrow f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in B$ for functions $f : A^n \to A$.  So the example of "normal subgroup" would be the case where you take the functions to be the collection of all conjugation operations $G \to G$.

Not sure why answers are posted as comments. This is not what they are made for.

There are some more interesting remarks that could be made here about impredicativity if that is what the asker is interested in (or finds difficult to understand) but that appears not to be the case. Sometimes it is necessary to clarify the question by having a conversation before posting an answer.

Let's hear it, please, @ZhenLin.

Is that really what you want know? For most mathematicians it is as irrelevant as debates about constructivity.

I don't know yet, @ZhenLin. Try me. If you need to post it as an answer to get enough space, then you're welcome to do so, as long as you preface it as too long for a comment. Also, I am not like most mathematicians: constructivity is interesting, and this looks interesting too (for what little I have seen about it). If you can answer the question I asked, too, then I just might award you the bounty!
